# Silent ruby/rails failure causes it to consume all memory and crash the server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, exception

I have a very strange bug which I'm in need of some clue on. Consider this:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :set_timezone

  def set_timezone
    if logged_in?
      Time.zone = current_user.time_zone
    end
  end
```

When PayPal tries to send a notification, it comes in like so:

```
Started POST "/ipn_subscription_notifications" for 173.0.82.126 at 2012-03-15 04:11:45 -0400
  Processing by IpnSubscriptionNotificationsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"txn_type"=>"subscr_signup", etc...
```

And here it gets hung up. Ruby begins chewing up memory until the machine crashes. This is the fix:

```
def set_timezone
  if current_user
    Time.zone = current_user.time_zone
  end
end
```

Let's look at `logged_in?`:

```
module AuthenticatedSystem
  def logged_in?
    current_user ? true : false
  end
```

Which is logically equivalent to the fix.

I suspect an error is being thrown and caught, and somebody is restarting the request process. `AuthenticatedSystem` is certainly suspect.

This does not happen in the development environment, it throws an error and returns 500:

```
Started POST "/ipn_subscription_notifications" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-03-15 15:19:39 -0700
  Processing by IpnSubscriptionNotificationsController#create as */*
  Parameters: {"foobar"=>nil}
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 9ms

NoMethodError (undefined method `logged_in?' for #<IpnSubscriptionNotificationsController:0xdfdaaf4>):
  app/controllers/application_controller.rb:8:in `set_timezone'

Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@ce2/gems/actionpack-3.1.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.erb (1.3ms)
Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@ce2/gems/actionpack-3.1.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.erb (1.0ms)
Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@ce2/gems/actionpack-3.1.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.erb within rescues/layout (4.8ms)
[2012-03-15 15:19:40] ERROR Errno::ECONNRESET: Connection reset by peer
  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:56:in `eof?'
  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:56:in `run'
  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:183:in `block in start_thread'
```

Detecting such failures and handling them gracefully is my goal.

Any ideas? Can I instrument Passenger, or some other part of the Rails stack?

Comment: rvm info, and bundle show: http://sync.in/86yKG0Qg2f

Comment: Are you using `restful-authentication`? If so, which fork?

Comment: I am not using restful-authentication, but rather authlogic (2.1.6 03ed66a)

Comment: So where is `AuthenticatedSystem` coming from? That's not part of authlogic.

Comment: It's part of a gem called CommunityEngine. I think they started with restful-authentication, and swapped AuthLogic in 2 years ago: https://github.com/bborn/communityengine/commit/83e603db851e6c95b1196f5253f6a53bd08cd509

Comment: I figured out the root cause: because this filter exists in ApplicationController, it's not picking up the 'include AuthenticatedSystem' in BaseController. Regular users don't have a problem, because they're hitting Controllers that inherit from BaseController. IpnSubscriptionNotificationsController, inheriting from ApplicationController, doesn't pick that up.

Comment: That's good to know, but the original question remains. Why am I not getting an error on staging? How is ruby spinning off into lala land, and can that be handled more gracefully?

Comment: Since this happens in production only, and the 500 rendering is different in production vs development, perhaps the infinite loop is happening in the production 500 error rendering? Try running locally in production mode, and see what happens. Also try putting a `debugger` line before the line that triggers the error, so you can see where the code starts looping. You'll need to temporarily put the ruby-debug (or ruby-debug19 for Ruby 1.9.x) gem into the main section of your Gemfile for `debugger` to work in production mode.

Answer (score 0):

the error is undefined method logged_in? in your IpnSubscriptionNotificationsController, and this controller inherit from ApplicationController, are u sure include AuthenticatedSystem module in your ApplicationController, may be u can try this first

Answer (score 0):

May be this does not resolve your problem, but you should use around_filter :set_timezone instead of before filter. Take a look at this: http://www.elabs.se/blog/36-working-with-time-zones-in-ruby-on-rails#working_with_multiple_user_time_zones